# Linux: How to check total number of bytes written to memory by a process

Tags: linux, memory, process, memory-usage, write

Note: I know about the commands like `top` but I am interested in knowing the number of bytes written to memory and also rewrites (number of times storing to the memory happened)

Comment: Take a look at vmstat command and also at the ps command which has parameters about process memory usage.

Comment: I don't think such statistics are available as they would have a big effect on performance.

Comment: Here's an older question that looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457342/trying-to-trap-all-memory-reads-writes-on-a-linux-machine

Comment: What problem are you solving? Which tool to use depends on if you are a developer who can tolerate massive overhead to prove memory use correctness (Valgrind)  or a production system that needs to run at a usable speed while sampling (Linux perf_events)

Comment: I tried using perf mem but it doesn't reflect anything in terms of bytes (memory).

Answer (score 0):

There are some per-CPU/per-socket counters which can be useful, e.g. [this set of notes](https://github.com/LucaCanali/Miscellaneous/blob/master/Spark_Notes/Tools_Linux_Memory_Perf_Measure.md) among other things points to https://github.com/intel/pcm. It has a tool to measure per-socket memory bandwidth on Intel processors.

If you are investigating some specific application you may [pin it to a specific core](https://baiweiblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/02/how-to-set-processor-affinity-in-linux-using-taskset/), make sure nothing else runs on it and use per-socket stats provided by Intel's tool.